# JSON is working but can't get JSONP to work

Tags: jquery, json

Hello i've been working to get som json to work.

I've written this little piece of code:

```
$.getJSON("/calendar/event/test", function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(i,item){
    $('#test').append('<li>' + item.title + '</li>');
  });
});
```

This works perfectly and appends the titles returned from the JSON object...

What doesn't work is when I want a webapp to retrieve the data. This webapp is located on another domain.

I tried to change the above JSON code into a simple JSONP piece of code by doing this:

```
$.getJSON("http://domainname.com/calendar/event/test?callback=?", function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(i,item){
    $('#test').append('<li>' + item.title + '</li>');
  });
});
```

But this doesn't work. I get this error code: parsererror - Error: jQuery1710762373415816335_1330535356545 was not called... However, if I try to retrieve some data through JSONP from e.g. Wikipedia - this works. So maybe it's a server setting or something similar?

I can't figure this out, and any help in any direction is gladly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server needs to return proper [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). JSON is not the same thing as JSONP, JSONP has an added layer in that it is wrapped in a callback named after the GET parameter that was passed containing a callback name. For example, this would be valid JSONP:

```
thecallbackname({"key":"value"})
```

Comment: Ah. Okay, thanks. I will try work a bit ahead with this, and try to figure out how it works :)

Comment: I found this guide helpfull: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/